# Using strings instead of symbols: good or evil?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Often enough, I find myself dealing with lists of function options (or more general replacement lists) of the form `{foo->value,...}`.  This leads to bugs when foo already has a value in $Context.  One obvious way to prevent this is using a string "foo" instead of the symbol: `{"foo"->value,...}`.  This works, but seems to draw ire of some seasoned LISPers I know, who chastise me for conflating symbols and strings and tell me to use built-in quoting constructs.

While it *is* certainly possible to write code that avoids collisions without using strings, it often seems more trouble than it is worth. On the other hand, I haven't seen too many examples of `{"string"->value}` type replacement rules.  So the question to you is -- is this an acceptable usage pattern?..  Are there cases where it is particularly appropriate?..  Where should it be avoided?..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In my opinion (disclaimer - it is only my opinion), it is best to avoid using strings as option names, at least for "main" options in your function. Strings OTOH are totally fine as settings (r.h.s. of options). This is not to say that you can not use strings, just as you noted. Perhaps, they could be more appropriate for sub-options, and they are used in this way by many system functions (usually "superfunctions" like `NDSolve`, that may have sub-options within options). The main problems I see with using strings is that they reduce the introspection capabilities, both for the system and for the user. In other words, it is harder to discover an option that has a string name than that with a symbol name - for the latter I can just inspect the names of the symbols in a package, and also symbolic option names have usage messages. You may also want to automate some things, such as writing a utility that finds all option names in the package etc. It is easier to do when option names are symbols, since they all belong to the same context. It is also easy to discover that some options do not have usage messages, one can do that automatically by writing a utility function.

Finally, you may have a better protection against accidental collisions of similar option names. It may be, that many option sequences are passed to your function, and occasionally they may contain options with the same name. If option names were symbols, full symbol names would be different. Then, you will both get a shadowing warning, and at the same time a protection - only the correct option (full) name will be used. For string, you don't get any warning, and may end up using incorrect option setting, if the duplicate string option name with a wrong setting (intended for a different function, say) happens to be first in the list. This scenario is more likely to occur in larger projects, but bugs like this are probably very hard to catch (this is a guess, I never had such situation).

As for possible collisions, if you follow some naming conventions such as option name always starting with a capital letter, plus put most of your code in packages, and do not start your variable or function names (for functions in the interactive session), with a capital letter, then you will greatly reduce the chance of such collisions. Additionally, you should `Protect` option names, when you define them, or at the end of the package. Then, the collisions will be detected as cases of shadowing. Avoiding shadowing, OTOH, is a general necessity, so the case of options is no more special in this respect than for function names etc.

Comment: +1  Technically, capitalized symbols are reserved for Mathematica built-ins, but this convention is widely ignored.  The reason is that one can be virtually certain that a capitalized symbol will not have a down value.  I try to respect the reservation for function names, but in the case of options I routinely define my own using capitalized names.

Comment: @WReach: capitalized names are only reserved for symbols in the `System'` context. Other rules are just conventions, and moreover, only for the symbols created in interactive sessions, not in packages. In packages, a convention is to capitalize exported functions, and option names. This can be seen in many add-on packages, both produced by WRI and third parties. Also, this is the advice that Roman Maeder gives in his "Programming in Mathematica", which is a standard reference, especially for package-writing. Since full names are different,collisions will result in shadowing, so one gets warned

Comment: +1 "The main problems I see with using strings is that they reduce the introspection capabilities"

Comment: +1 Also, (v9) autocompletion won't work on string option names.